# Telerik Reports - Localizing Expressions

Tags: localization, telerik-reporting

We are currently using telerik reports that needs to be localized. Is there any way to localize text that was set in expressions on textboxes like below?

```
Ex. =iif(Fields.IsValid = 1, "Text Example 1", "Text Example 2")
```